# Does anyone know a "Known issues" wiki for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

sorry, crosspost from here:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76898/466998.aspx

Does anyone know a good wiki for WP7 where we can collect bugs, best practice or known issues? Don't want to set up my own if there is already a famous one "out there". And stackoverflow is not really a wiki, even though its really helpful.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WP7Dev wiki on WikiSpaces](http://wp7dev.wikispaces.com/) is probably the closest to what you're asking for.